# Regular Expression Quantifiers Python

Tags: python, regex

Hi guys I can't Understand How this regular expression quantifiers works :

```
\w{,2}
```

when I apply it on my text this result will show up:

[image]

Comment: use regex101 and read the explanation: https://regex101.com/r/Ld7JPj/1 :  _\w{,2} matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9\_])
{,2} Quantifier — Matches between 0 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`\w` means a *word symbol:* any **letter**, **digit** or **underscore symbol**.

`{,2}` means the number of those symbols — 0 to 2 symbols.

[image]

Note that it match *zero (0)* symbols, too, which may be dangerous.

You may see it by alternating yellow and blue colors in the picture, e.g. between `My` and `na`me, which are both yellow, so there **have to be something blue** between them - it is a **0-symbols match** just after the `My`.

---

*Note:*

You used [pythex](https://pythex.org/), which doesn't alternate colors, so you are not able to distinguish individual matching parts.

Use other regex editor, e.g. [regex101](https://regex101.com/):

[image]

---

*In detail:*

1. Trying 0 to 2 `\w` symbols match in `My name is Furat`:

   - 0-symbols match just before `My` — continues trying 1-symbol match.
   - 1-symbol match: `M` — continues trying 2-symbols match.
   - 2-symbols match: `My` — stop, reached the maximum allowed symbols.

   **So the first match is `My`.**
2. Trying 0 to 2 `\w` symbols match in the remaining part   `name is Furat`:

   - 0-symbols match just before (the space in)  `name` — continues trying 1-symbol match.
   - no success — space symbol is neither a letter, nor a digit, nor an underscore character.

   **So the second match is only 0-symbols match just before (the space in)  `name`.**

   *Advancing one character after 0-symbols match, so the remaining part is* `name is Furat`.
3. Trying 0 to 2 `\w` symbols match in the remaining part  `name is Furat`:

   - 0-symbols match just before `name` — continues trying 1-symbol match.
   - 1-symbol match: `n` — continues trying 2-symbols match.
   - 2-symbols match: `na` — stop, reached maximum allowed symbols.

   **So the third match is `na`.**
4. ... and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it yet

Comment: I expanded my answer. As you can see, matches occur in **pairs** of letters/digits, in remaining **1**-letter/digit, and — which you don't see in my picture — in **zero** letter/digits, too.

Comment: Never omit leading `0` in the limiting quantifiers, `{,2}` might mean something else in other regex flavors, it may either cause a crash or match 3 chars all of a sudden.

Comment: @Wiktor, it is not *my* regular expression, it is the OP's one. So your comment would be IMHO more useful as a comment *on the question itself.* OP wanted to explain namely *this* regex.